# Print length of strings from each line of stdin in python

Tags: python, string, input, line, stdin

I want to print length of each string from stdin. The number of strings is not given. Please suggest some way. What I am trying is:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    s= str(line)
    print len(s),
```

for example, input is:

```
ram
sita
geeta
```

The required output is `3 4 5` but it is printing `4 5 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the

```
ram
sita
geeta
```

Actually is...

```
ram\n
sita\n
geeta
```

And...

```
>>> len('\n')
1
>>> len('ram\n')
4
>>>
```

So you need...

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    s = str(line.strip())
    print len(s),
```

Demo:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python2 test.py 
ram
sita
geeta
3 4 5
[user@localhost ~]$
```

About what is [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

> **strip(...)**
>
> *S.strip([chars]) -> str*
>
> Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
>      whitespace removed.
>      If chars is given and not `None`, remove characters in chars instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can `str.rstrip` over the input to remove any newlines and use `end=" "` with print to get the output on the same line separated by a space

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print(*(len(line.rstrip()) for line in  sys.stdin),end= " ")
```